# Is the set open or closed?

Tags: general-topology, functions, smooth-functions

Let f be a smooth function with $f: Ω⊂R^m→R$ Is the set $\{(x,y)∈Ω×R|y=f(x)\}$ open?

A set is considered open if, for every point within the set, you can find a small enough region around that point that is entirely contained within the set.

I am thinking that the set is open since in our case, for any point $(x, f(x))$ on the graph, you can find a small enough neighborhood around it (in the domain $Ω$) such that all the points in that neighborhood, when combined with the corresponding y values (i.e., $f(x)$), lie within the graph.

Am I right that the set is open? Its not really mathematically shown since I argued in a more informal way.

Comment: It's a graph. In the simplest case $m =1$ it's just a bendy line. It's clearly closed and not open unless it's the whole space or is trivial.

Comment: Graphs of continuous functions are closed in a pretty general setting of Hausdorff spaces.

Comment: Consider $F:\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $F(x, y) := y-f(x)$. Then your set is $F^{-1}(\lbrace 0 \rbrace)$. What do you know about preimages of continuous functions? Moreover, which sets are closed and open at once?

Comment: Not even continuity of $f$ is necessary to answer the question. You need continuity to show the graph is closed, but just the fact that $f$ is a function in $\Bbb R$ is enough to show the graph is not open. Let $(x_0, f(x_0))$ be a point on the graph. Every neighborhood of that point contains points $(x_0, y)$ for $y \ne f(x_0)$, which are thus not in the graph.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem using the significantly weaker assumption that $f$ is continuous. As $\mathbb{R}$ is Hausdorff, it follows that the graph $G_f=\{(x, y) \in \Omega \times R : f(x) = y\}$) is closed in $\Omega \times R$ (see [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_graph_property#Sufficient_conditions_for_a_closed_graph) on Wikipedia and the reference on the sufficient conditions section for more details).

Showing that $G_f$ is closed is not sufficient in showing that it is not open, so we'll now prove that indeed it is indeed not open: we'll argue by contradiction, so suppose that $G_f$ is clopen. Let $x \in \Omega$ be an arbitrary point and consider its connected component $X \subseteq \Omega$. As $X$ and $R$ are connected, so is their product $X \times R$. Restricting $G_f$ to the subspace $X \times R$, we obtain the clopen set $G_f \cap (X \times R)$, which together with the fact that $X \times R$ need be connected, implies that either $G_f \cap (X \times R) = \emptyset$ or that $G_f \cap (X \times R) = (X \times R)$, both cases being visibly nonsense.

I don't think that some sort of informal reasoning is feasible in solving a technical problem as such, if you want to read more on topology, I wholeheartedly recommend reading [Mendelson's introduction to topology](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=FWFmoEUJSwkC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_book_other_versions_r&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) as a first book on the topic - I personally found it very "user-friendly" when I was younger.